# AngularJS - Uncaught Error: No module: myApp

Tags: angularjs

I just finished reading documentation and watching numerous angularjs videos and decided to start working with it.

I decided to start with a small simple example and after fiddling for an hour and not being able to get it off the ground I am starting to wonder if it is me or something undetected after all..

SO my simple code started getting reduced and eventually I simply copied and pasted this fiddle code to see if that would work (since it works on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/FssbL/1/

The code in my browser does not work...

I even reduced it to less code

my tad.js file contains this code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: "Hello"};
});
```

My html file contains this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/tad.js"></script>
</head>

<html>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">   

        <h1> {{data.message + " world"}} </h1>

    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle works for me! :)

Comment: I've copy and pasted your code form this question (together with angular.min.js from angularjs.org), and it works fine

Comment: ohhh gosh! I apologize profusely! I had a tad.js file loading from js directory but the one I was editing was in the root... lesson learned... check if the source files ARE the right files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a tad.js file loading from js directory but the one I was editing was in the root... lesson learned... check if the source files ARE the right files!